# Firebase Crashlytics reporting crash on iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

I am getting a crash on firebase on SKStoreProductViewController, while during testing this crash is not being produced.
Is there anyway to resolve this issue? Thanks.

> Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
> -[SKStoreProductViewController sceneDisconnected:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

How to resolve the reported issue?

Answer (score 0):

This crash happens in the public release of iOS/iPadOS 15.7, and seed releases of iOS/iPadOS 16 prior to seed 4 [1]. It does not occur in the public release of iOS 16.

The crash primarily happens when the app is in the background and is about to be terminated by the operating system. As a result, these crashes are not expected to be visible to the majority of end users. (One exception is on iPad with an app that supports multiple scenes, and a user manually terminates a scene.)

Your analytics will show an increased in crash rate, however your customers should not be affected by this issue.

You can refer to https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/714464

Comment: But I am receiving this crash now even in iOS 16, 16.2 public releases.